Cannot deploy contract as it runs out of gas using the Remix IDE
I am getting the following trying to deploy a contract deployed to Sepolia using the Remix IDE:

creation of XYZContract errored: Error occurred: contract creation
code storage out of gas. contract creation code storage out of gas You
may want to cautiously increase the gas limit if the transaction went
out of gas.

The odd part is it is already deployed on Sepolia as is (exact code) and it deploys to VM fine. I have deployed many many contracts via Remix and not seen this issue before. It is a large contract but the exact code deployed not 1 week ago.
As good measure, after a successful deployment to a VM, I copied the gas and doubled it. I then used this doubled value for the custom gas - made no difference.
Note: I have enabled optimization using 1000 runs
Anyone have any idea of what is going on, maybe a bug with Remix? - I say this because the contract that was deployed was 0.08466609 in tx fee (and as mentioned is huge) but I created some small test contracts that should be very very cheap to deploy and they are estimated at around 0.6...
EDIT: I'm sure its a Remix bug because I cant deploy any of my other contracts that I KNOW work with the same error message (large and small)

Currently, there’s some issue with Ethereum Sepolia testnet. The gas fees are spiked.

Yea, I switched the network to Polygon test and the same contract deployed fine. As you say seems like a Sepolia testnet issue (congestion?).


@notice The L1StandardBridge is responsible for transfering ETH and
ERC20 tokens between L1 and ///         L2. In the case that an ERC20
token is native to L1, it will be escrowed within this ///
contract. If the ERC20 token is native to L2, it will be burnt. Before
Bedrock, ETH was ///         stored within this contract. After
Bedrock , ETH is instead stored inside the ///         OptimismPortal
contract. ///         NOTE: this contract is not intended to support
all variations of ERC20 tokens. Examples ///         of some token
types that may not be properly supported by this contract include, but
are ///         not limited to: tokens with transfer fees, rebasing
tokens, and tokens with blocklists.

This is the contract I feel is responsible
