Cant deploy smart contracts on Polygon Amoy or Sepolia
I have been trying to deploy a simple smart contarct to make custom ERC20 tokens:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.20;

import {ERC20} from "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract OZToken is ERC20 {
    uint dec = 10 ** 18;
    constructor() ERC20("OZToken", "OZT") {
        _mint(msg.sender, 1000 * dec);
    }
}

but I am having these errors and I dont know how to solve them. This error comes when I try to deploy on Amoy using npx hardhat ignition deploy ./ignition/modules/OZToken.ts --network amoy:
dane@ubuntu:~/Desktop/Contracts/applications$ npx hardhat ignition deploy ./ignition/modules/OZToken.ts --network amoy
✔ Confirm deploy to network amoy (11155111)? … yes
Hardhat Ignition 

Resuming existing deployment from ./ignition/deployments/chain-11155111

Deploying [ OZTokenModule ]

Warning - previously executed futures are not in the module:
 - WalletModule#EtherWallet

Batch #1
  Executing OZTokenModule#OZToken...

An unexpected error occurred:

IgnitionError: IGN410: Gas estimation failed: gas required exceeds allowance (190337)
    at sendTransactionForOnchainInteraction (/home/dane/Desktop/Contracts/applications/node_modules/@nomicfoundation/ignition-core/src/internal/execution/future-processor/helpers/network-interaction-execution.ts:181:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async sendTransaction (/home/dane/Desktop/Contracts/applications/node_modules/@nomicfoundation/ignition-core/src/internal/execution/future-processor/handlers/send-transaction.ts:85:18)
    at async FutureProcessor.processFuture (/home/dane/Desktop/Contracts/applications/node_modules/@nomicfoundation/ignition-core/src/internal/execution/future-processor/future-processor.ts:117:9)
    at async ExecutionEngine._executeBatch (/home/dane/Desktop/Contracts/applications/node_modules/@nomicfoundation/ignition-core/src/internal/execution/execution-engine.ts:155:30)
    at async ExecutionEngine.executeModule (/home/dane/Desktop/Contracts/applications/node_modules/@nomicfoundation/ignition-core/src/internal/execution/execution-engine.ts:116:25)
    at async Deployer.deploy (/home/dane/Desktop/Contracts/applications/node_modules/@nomicfoundation/ignition-core/src/internal/deployer.ts:196:25)
    at async SimpleTaskDefinition.action (/home/dane/Desktop/Contracts/applications/node_modules/@nomicfoundation/hardhat-ignition/src/index.ts:318:24)
    at async Environment._runTaskDefinition (/home/dane/Desktop/Contracts/applications/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/core/runtime-environment.ts:351:14)
    at async Environment.run (/home/dane/Desktop/Contracts/applications/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/core/runtime-environment.ts:184:14)

I think it says the gas limit is not set a appropriately. Below are my configuration files, please take look if I am missing something !!
./ignition/modules/OZToken.ts
import { buildModule } from "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-ignition/modules";

const OZTokenModule = buildModule("OZTokenModule", (m) => {
  const token = m.contract("OZToken");
  return { token };
});

module.exports = OZTokenModule;

hardhat.config.ts

import { HardhatUserConfig } from "hardhat/config";
import "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox";
import "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-ignition";
import * as dotenv from "dotenv";

dotenv.config();

const INFURA_API = process.env.INFURA_API_KEY;
const ALCHEMY_API = process.env.ALCHEMY_API_KEY;
const pvt_key = process.env.PRIVATE_KEY || "";

const config: HardhatUserConfig = {
  solidity: "0.8.20",
  networks: {
    sepolia: {
      url: `https://sepolia.infura.io/v3/${INFURA_API}`,
      accounts: [pvt_key],
      gas: 1000000,
      gasPrice: 20000000,
    },
    amoy: {
      url: `https://eth-sepolia.g.alchemy.com/v2/${ALCHEMY_API}`,
      accounts: [pvt_key],
      gas: 1000000,
      gasPrice: 20000000,
    },
  },
};

export default config;

Moreover, it is working perfectly in the hardhat local network, but not in remote networks

Something is wrong with Sepolia at the moment: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/166095/cannot-deploy-contract-as-it-runs-out-of-gas-using-the-remix-ide

You can use gasMultiplier paramter on per-network basis, for example:
    sepolia: {
        url: `http://host:port/`,
        accounts: process.env.SEPOLIA_PRIVATE_KEY !== undefined ? [process.env.SEPOLIA_PRIVATE_KEY] : [],
        gasMultiplier: 2,
    },

the above will double the gasLimit for Sepolia. Different networks have different gas requirements

Try to remove the gas and gasPrice from the hardhat.config.js file.
   const config: HardhatUserConfig = {
     solidity: "0.8.20",
     networks: {
       sepolia: {
         url: `https://sepolia.infura.io/v3/${INFURA_API}`,
         accounts: [pvt_key],
        },
        amoy: {
          url: `https://ethsepolia.g.alchemy.com/v2/${ALCHEMY_API}`,
          accounts: [pvt_key],
         },
        },
       };

change this in your hardhat file or just remove the gas and gasPrice key from the hardhat config file. The hardhat will auto call the estimateGas function and calculate the gas fees required for the transaction.
